# Recompile dependent Stylus files by Gulp

Tags: gulp, stylus, gulp-watch

I've something like this:

```
stylus/
    dashboard.styl
    default.styl
```

*It's so much more complex than that, but trying to hit the point.*

( for example ) inside `dashboard.styl`, I **@require**d `default.styl`. When I make any change or modifications on `default.styl`, *Gulp* ( or *gulp-watch* or anything that should do ) doesn't recompile dependent files.

When I say *dependent files*, I mean `dashboard.styl`.

I think, `dashboard.styl` that has `default.styl` as **@require** is dependent on `default.styl`; So, when it get changed, `dashboard.styl` should get too. But *gulp-watch* doesn't understand this.

Question:
**How to recompile files that required a changed file inside of them?**

---

Some additional information

*gulpfile.js*

```
;!( function( w ) {

    'use strict';

    var gulp = require( 'gulp' ),
        stylus = require( 'gulp-stylus' ),

        watch = require( 'gulp-watch' ),

        plumber = require( 'gulp-plumber' ),

        stylusPath = 'public/stylus',
        cssPath = 'public/css';

    gulp.task( 'default', function() {

        gulp.src( stylusPath + '/*.styl' ).pipe( plumber() ).pipe( watch( stylusPath + '/*.styl' ) ).pipe( stylus({

            compress: true

        }) ).pipe( gulp.dest( cssPath ) );

    });

})( module );
```

---

How I'm doing this manually now:

When I make some change on `default.styl`, I will go to *Command Prompt*, stop the currently running task, and re-run it using `gulp` command. It makes the gulp to compile all of files at the first step, and this is what I want ( *clarify:* I have to want this! There's no other option ).

---

What's not an answer: I don't want to

- write something to compile all of my files on every change.
- compile my files manually.

I need someone to tell me **there is** a way to achieve this and how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for but here is how I would accomplish what you're trying to do. I would create two separate gulp tasks, one to watch and one to compile. Similar to what I have bellow. This way anytime a stylus file is changed in your stylus folder which you specified in the watch task it will re-run your gulp stylus compile task.

```js
//Watch said files
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  watch('/stylus-folder/', function() { gulp.start('stylus'); });
});

//run task when files are changed
gulp.task('stylus', function () {
  gulp.src(stylusPath + '/*.styl')
     .pipe(plumber() )
     .pipe(stylus({
        compress: true
      }))
     .pipe(gulp.dest(cssPath ));
});
```

Comment: It starts to recompile all of my Stylus files, that i said this is not an answer clearly; Thanks BTW.

Comment: Sorry your phrasing is a bit confusing, nevertheless, I think I know what your trying to do.  What you need to do is integrate [gulp-changed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed) within your workflow.

Comment: you're right absolutely; It's complicated to explain what i'm exactly looking for. But i think **gulp-change** can solve my problem. let me test that. will update here.

Comment: That wasn't what I was looking for. Because some of my files need to recompile without any actual change. They included file **a.styl**, now when a change happens on **a.styl** it can't recognize that change; but needs to recompile it.